# Array Operations to add / remove entries from 1 to another

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I have 2 sets of array:

Data:

```
$data = [
    [
        'company_code' => 'ABC',
        'supplier_codes' => [
            'S-2',
            'S-3',
            'S-5',
        ],
    ],
];
```

Source (from database):

```
$database = [
    'company_code' => 'ABC',
    'suppliers' => [
        [
            'code' => 'S-1',
        ],
        [
            'code' => 'S-2',
            'reference' => '12345'
        ],
        [
            'code' => 'S-3',
        ],
        [
            'code' => 'S-4',
            'reference' => 'some string',
        ]
    ],
];
```

What I need to achieve:

- If a supplier code is missing in `$data` but exists in `$database`,
  remove it from `$database`.
- If a supplier code exists in `$data` but missing in `$database`, add     it into `$database`

The output of the example here should be as follows:

```
$output = [
    'company_code' => 'ABC',
    'suppliers' => [
        [
            'code' => 'S-2',
            'reference' => '12345'
        ],
        [
            'code' => 'S-3',
        ],
        [
            'code' => 'S-5',
        ]
    ],
];
```

I was thinking of removing the `suppliers` subarray, then reconstruct the structure based on the data from `supplier_codes`. But the problem is some of the entries in `suppliers` may have an optional field called `reference`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I end up solving my problem this way:

```
$result = $database;
$result['suppliers'] = [];

foreach($data as $tag) {
    foreach($tag['supplier_codes'] as $code) {
        $found = false;
        foreach($database['suppliers'] as $supplier) {
            if($supplier['code'] === $code) {
                $result['suppliers'][] = $supplier;
                $found = true;
            }
        }

        if(!$found) {
            $result['suppliers'][] = ['code' => $code];
        }
    }
}
```

Output of `print_r($result);`:

```
Array
(
    [company_code] => ABC
    [suppliers] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [code] => S-2
                    [reference] => 12345
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [code] => S-3
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [code] => S-5
                )
        )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    <?php
$data = [
    [
        'company_code' => 'ABC',
        'supplier_codes' => ['S-2','S-3','S-5'],
    ],
];
$database = [
    'company_code' => 'ABC',
    'suppliers' => [
        [
            'code' => 'S-1',
        ],
        [
            'code' => 'S-2',
            'reference' => '12345'
        ],
        [
            'code' => 'S-3',
        ],
        [
            'code' => 'S-4',
            'reference' => 'some string',
        ]
    ],
];


foreach($database['suppliers'] as $k=>$v){
    foreach($data as $kd=>$vd){
        $valueremove = false;
        $removeIndex = '';
        foreach($vd['supplier_codes'] as $key=>$val){
            if($val == $v['code']){
                $valueremove = false;
                $removeIndex = '';
                break;
            } else {
                $valueremove = true;
                $removeIndex = $k;
            }
        }

        if($valueremove == true){
            unset($database['suppliers'][$removeIndex]);
        } else {
            $valueinsert = false;
            foreach($data as $kd=>$vd){
                foreach($vd['supplier_codes'] as $key=>$val){
                    foreach($database['suppliers'] as $kc=>$vc){
                        if($val == $vc['code']){
                            $valueinsert = false;
                            $insertIndex = '';
                            $insertVal = '';
                            break;
                        } else {
                            $valueinsert = true;
                            $insertIndex = count($database['suppliers'])+1;
                            $insertVal = $val;
                        }
                    }
                    if($valueinsert == true){
                        $database['suppliers'][$insertIndex] = array('code'=>$insertVal);
                    }
                }


            }

        }
    }
}
echo "<PRE>"; print_r($database);
```